# Where should we actually need to set the token price?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I have seen a video which sets the "token price" in a contract using that token (erc20), If the same token is used in another contact for transferring in another contract with a different value of "token price" then is the token acceptable in the exchanges?

And is it the correct way of setting the token price ?

Comment: Hi there. Your question isn't clear. Normally you can only manually set the token price in a token sale/ICO contract. Once the token sale has finished, then people and exchanges are free to trade your token at a price that is set by the markets: your initial token sale price becomes irrelevant. Are you saying there are two token sale contracts selling the same token for different prices?

Comment: Yeah exactly , suppose I am making an auction which uses a token for the transfer of money . Is it relevant to use a token or simply transfer eth ?

Comment: If ether is feasible then don't add complexity and friction with a token.